# How to send textbox text to another form through WAN C#

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, wan

I want to know how can I send a textbox text through WAN and the other form open in another computer uses the text that I sent as his textbox text.

Basically it's sending a control data to another form that is open in another computer.

How can I do this? I thought on using TCP or something but I didn't understand so much that I could modify it to send large texts and use it.

Comment: Nicolas, you are running a WinForms app on PC A and another WinForms app on PC B. You want to send data from PC A to PC B. Is this your question?

Comment: Yeah! That was exactly what I tried to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Nicolas, now that we are clear: the most straightforward way of doing this is opening a socket to send your data. Although I believe this is a bit exagerated for most scenarios, it may resolve your problem.

Note, however, that if you have an assynchronous scenario (that is, user at PC B do not knows when user at PC A is ready to send data), then PC B (the receiver) will have to keep the socket opened, what is a bad idea. Try to figure out if you can "schedule" when data will be sent.

Take a look at [this little tutorial](http://www.csharp-examples.net/socket-send-receive/). Create a new project only to learn how to send and receive data from a socket.
When you find any touble, do a little search about it. There are lots of references on the internet, including at StackOverflow.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, Andre. But I didn't find any reference on how to send large data through sockets. I'm not a professional C# programmer, I'm more like average. If you found anything that reefers right into what I want, please send it to me.

Comment: Nicolas, what do you mean by large data? A string, maybe? Notice that the *send* method receives a byte[], you can convert your string to this array by using Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(yourString).